# Add console application command prompt parameters

Tags: visual-c++, console-application

When I debug console application in MSVC, it opens the Command prompt first to print output or read input. How can I make that Command prompt window start with "cmd /u" parameters (but not pass those parameters to my console application)?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve, but you are probably looking for `Project > Properties > Debugging > Command`. This usually reads `$(TargetPath)`, but you could set it to `cmd /u $(TargetPath)` instead.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik This is what I was looking for, thank you! Could you please form it up as an answer so I can accept it?